# My HP Pavilion g7 is not detecting external monitor. It is running Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, external-display, hp-pavilion, ubuntu-13.04

I have confirmed that both the cable and monitor are working perfectly. I get `No signal` and `No Display` when connecting my Laptop to an external display.

The cable is VGA and the person using the computer before me said it was working fine.

```
product: HP Pavilion g7 Notebook PC (QE124UA#ABA)
vendor: Hewlett-Packard
version: 0691120000204610000620100
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=103C_5335KV G=N L=CON B=HP S=PAV X=Null sku=QE124UA#ABA uuid=35434431-3339-3158-3959-441EA1E2865E
```

[Hardware specifications](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03024325)

P.S. I've tried different working cables and monitors. So it's not a monitor issue.

Comment: How have you confirmed that the cable and monitor are working? Is the cable VGA or DVI or HDMI? Did it ever work before and if yes what has changed?

Comment: sorry not to mention that. I've tried on different working cables and monitors.

Comment: Better also answer my other questions.

Comment: @harrymc sorry. it's a company PC so I'm told by guy who used it before that it used run on Windows and was working. He said it even worked for him after installing the Ubuntu. Now the monitor is not getting any signal.

Comment: Is the cable VGA or DVI or HDMI?

Comment: @harrymc it's VGA

Comment: Please try and comment upon the answers in [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/234153/external-monitor-recognized-but-getting-no-signal).

Comment: Do you have dual boot? In that case, does it work with Windows? That will at least rule out any hardware issues..

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon for things to stop working in Ubuntu (touch pads, monitors, wireless cards) after a kernel update. This seems likely since it apparently worked for the previous owner.

Roll back your Linux kernel to the previous version through the Grub menu and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enables the external display in Ubuntu?
usually laptops have a display switching button.
Why don't you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the BIOS needs configuring, for example "LCD and analog RGB" instead of "autodetect".

On some laptops a monitor is only detected if it's present at power-on.

Some laptops have a keyboard shortcut such as Fn+F4 or Fn+F7.

Your can also try entering :

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --auto
xrandr --output VGA1 --off
xrandr --output VGA1 --auto
```

Also ensure that you have the latest driver for your video card.